# JSON parse Error. Unexpected token U

Tags: php, ajax, json

I an getting a Desc :: parsererror |Error :: SyntaxError: Unexpected token U error for the following code. The php page is echoing JSON produced by `json_encode`, and also contains

```
 header("Content-type: application/json");
```

Here is the AJAX code.

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'questions/checkAnswer',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {questionId : questionIdValue, answer : answerValue},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(result){
                   console.log(result);

            },
            error:function(xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Desc :: "+desc+"\nError :: "+err);
            }
        });
```

Can anyone help me regarding where am I going wrong?

Comment: Show us the JSON response that the browser receives.

Comment: I am not sure I get you. If you are asking for the JSobject, then here it is {"question_id":"0","question_name":"Who won the last cricket cup?","choice_a":"India","choice_b":"Australia","choice_c":"South Africa","choice_d":"New Zealand"}

Comment: ...and what exactly is a "JSObject?" Do you mean ["JSON text?"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#section-2)

Comment: By that I meant the output of json_encode.. Am sorry if I messing things up. Have just started learning JS.

Answer (score 0):

If the response is not actually valid JSON but instead is "Unauthorized", meaning the server is returning a 401 error, then this could result.